# RDP-window doesn't react to keyboard simulation

Tags: c#, winapi, rdp

I use RemoteApp (~RDP) to access to the remote application and then I try to simulate some user activity with keyboard. But remote application doesn't react on that activity anyhow. 
The same simulation on the same application running locally works perfectly! But when I start to interact with the application remotely everything fails.
I have tried:

1. SendKeys.SendWait(string)
2. keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo)
3. SendInput and library over it InputSimulator (https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)

Nothing is good. The only one success is that remote application reacts on backspace.

Both machines are Win7 x64.

Do you have any suggestions or positive experience how to simulate keyboard activity with RDP-windows?

Comment: Have you tried UI Automation?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following solution - using AutoIt.

1. [Download](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) AutoIt from the official site and install it;
2. Add to the Referenses of your project the library AutoItX3.Assembly.dll. Not to be confused with libraries and AutoItX3.dll AutoItX3_x64.dll, it is essential;
3. Add `using AutoIt;` in the beginning of the file, which will work with the keyboard;
4. For keyboard simulation use the static method `AutoItX.Send(string)`;
5. The executable directory of the program must contain the library AutoItX3.Assembly.dll, AutoItX3.dll and AutoItX3_x64.dll. If you know for sure that your application will not be run on 32-bit or 64-bit operating systems, you can remove one of the libraries - AutoItX3.dll or AutoItX3_x64.dll accordingly.